# What is wrong with my LEFT JOIN? Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'LEFT JOIN rep.de_para_game as b on b.exe = a.name' at line 14

When I try to run:

```sql
drop table if exists rep.report_daily_gaming;
create table rep.report_daily_gaming as select 
date(a.date) as date,
a.name,
b.alias,
max(a.cpu) as cpu,
max(a.mem) as mem,
max(a.gpu_clock) as gpu_clock,
max(a.gpu_temp) as gpu_temp,
max(a.gpu_load) as gpu_load,
max(a.cpu_load) as cpu_load,
max(a.ram_load) as ram_load,
count(a.id) as minutes
from infos.gaming as a group by a.date, a.name
LEFT JOIN rep.de_para_game as b
on b.exe = a.name
```

But when I remove the "left join" and all "rep.de_para_game" references, it works. What is wrong with my left join?

Table Structures:

```sql
Name: infos.gaming
cpu double
cpu_load double
date datetime
gpu_clock double
gpu_load double
gpu_temp double
id mediumint
mem bigint
name varchar(255)
ram_load double
screen tinyint(1)
```

```sql
Name: rep.de_para_game
alias varchar(255)
exe varchar(255)
id mediumint
```

MySQL Server version

```sql
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| version       | 8.0.30 |
+---------------+--------+
```

Comment: incorrect syntax, `Group By` should be at last

Comment: `FROM ... JOIN... WHERE... GROUP BY`. You have `FROM ... GROUP BY ... JOIN`

Comment: [If only there were some kind of online guide or reference for the syntax of SELECT statements.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove group by before left join, try like this,

```sql
drop table if exists rep.report_daily_gaming;
create table rep.report_daily_gaming as select 
date(a.date) as date,
a.name,
b.alias,
max(a.cpu) as cpu,
max(a.mem) as mem,
max(a.gpu_clock) as gpu_clock,
max(a.gpu_temp) as gpu_temp,
max(a.gpu_load) as gpu_load,
max(a.cpu_load) as cpu_load,
max(a.ram_load) as ram_load,
count(a.id) as minutes
from infos.gaming
LEFT JOIN rep.de_para_game as b
on b.exe = a.name  
GROUP BY a.date
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use
**Group By**
in the end of statement

Comment: This is little more than a comment.

Comment: Why you think so?

Comment: Well, compare your answer to [Vinoth .R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11662383/vinoth-r)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73594534/what-is-wrong-with-my-left-join-syntax-error#comment129960048_73594534).

Comment: Why @vinoth-r's comment is cannot be an answer?